# Segregation of Duties search

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to write a SQL statement that will search a table for segregation of duties of issues. In my table there is a user column and a responsibility column. I want to pull all users who have two defined responsibilities. This was what I was trying, but it does not work:

```
SELECT Users.[User], Users.[Responsibility]
  FROM Users
 WHERE Users.[Responsibility]="Example A"
   And Users.[Responsibility]="Example B";
```

Any suggestions? I think it's not working because it's not basing the responsibilities on the user, but I'm not sure how to fix that.

Comment: it doesnt work is vague. what do you expect to see? and what data do you have in your table, some examples would help

Comment: Could you please include the table definition in your question? Including unique constraints etc.

Comment: It returns no results, when there are users who have Example A and Example B. I want the results to be only the users who have both the responsibilities defined in the query. In the table, users are listed are more than once if they have more than one responsibility.

Comment: PK is just a number 1 on down. Table has ID, Group, Responsibility, Application and User columns, but I'm only concerned with user and responsibility. If a user has more than one responsibility, then there are multiple rows for that user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following query will return a list of all users having *both* `'Example A'` and `'Example B'` as their `Responsibility`:

```
SELECT Users.[User]
FROM Users
GROUP BY [User]
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN [Responsibility]='Example A' THEN 1 END) >= 1 AND
       COUNT(CASE WHEN [Responsibility]='Example B' THEN 1 END) >= 1
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/494d1/1)

If you want to get all users having at least two different responsibilities (no matter which), then substitute `HAVING` clause by:

```
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT [Responsibility]) >= 2
```

**EDIT:**

Use the following query for MS-Access:

```
SELECT User
FROM Users
GROUP BY User
HAVING  SUM(IIF(Responsibility = "Example A", 1, 0)) >=1 
        AND  SUM(IIF(Responsibility = "Example B", 1, 0)) >= 1
```

Comment: I get an error that says "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'COUNT(CASE WHEN [Responsibility]="Example A" THEN 1 END) >= 1 AND COUNT(CASE WHEN [Responsibility]="Example B" THEN 1 END) >=1.'

Comment: @Daniel What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Do you know what is causing the error? Do I need to change something for it to run in Access?

Comment: @Daniel I tested my initial query against SQL Server. I have updated my query for MS-Access. It works on my end (Access 2013). Please tag your question accordingly.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, your edit worked for me though. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The query is actually very simple:

```
select  u.User
from    Users u
where   u.Responsibility in( 'Example A', 'Example B' )
group by u.User
having count(*) > 1;
```

Your attempt didn't work because there was no one row for any user with both 'Example A' *and* 'Example B'. So you have to check for 'Example A' or 'Example B' then count the results.

This assumes, of course, that the same responsibility will not be listed for the same user more than once.